# almost uniform convergence and uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis

Which is the difference between almost uniform convergence and uniform convergence of a sequence of functions? If it is possible an example, please.
Thank you

Comment: Did you at least read the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#Almost_uniform_convergence)?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. According to that, the sequence of functions n/sqrt(pi) exp(-n^2 t^2) for n-> Infinity has a u. convergence on R \ {0} to 0 and to Dirac delta in R (a. e. convergence)?

Comment: I was wrong. I wanted to say a u. convergence on R \ {0} to 0 and to Dirac delta in R (convergence in the sense of distributions )